# Reset "open with" setting for Chrome

Tags: google-chrome

I clicked on a phone number link on a site, Chrome prompted me to choose which app to open it with, such as Skype. I chose Chrome by mistake, now when I try to open any phone number link on any site nothing happens..

I can't for the life of me find where to clear that saved setting, the only thing I can find is vague "reset all your settings and data" suggestions.

Can't find any advice on this googling or anything so I've turned to the one place where people know everything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out this is a Windows 10 preference setting, similar to default apps used to open file extensions.